# How to add different image to list view on different selection in android?

Tags: android, listview

In my application,i have a custom list view with some text views and image.By default image view contains gray arrow mark image.I got up to here.my problem is when user click on some item in list,the arrow mark will change into blue color arrow mark image and remaining are all in gray color only . selected list item image will be in blue color.How i can do it.Please can any one help me.

Thanking in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this functionality by setting `tag` in integer to your list item when you creating them. And when you make a selection then just get `tag` and compare it with item `index` if condition satisfied then make change to that `index` according to your requirement and also change all other to items reverse

Comment: You can set tag as item index to imageview of arrow mark for which you have to change image, now on selection just check the selected item index and compare it to image tag if equal then just change color to  blue and rest of all to gray, hope you understood!

Answer (score 1):

In the getView() method of your adapter, implement the View.onclickLister and onclick of a particular item change the drawable of that arrow to blue.

```
    private int resource;
private Context mContext;
public int mPosition;
public static int curSelected = -1;
static String time ;


public CustomDateRowAdapter(Context context, int _resource,
        List<DayPickerTo> objects,) {
    super(context, _resource, objects);
    allItems = objects;
    resource = _resource;
    mContext = context;


}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
        final ViewGroup parent) {

    RelativeLayout rel = null;
    if (null == convertView) {

        String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(inflater);
        rel = (RelativeLayout) vi.inflate(resource, rel, true);

    } else {
        rel = (RelativeLayout) convertView;

    }

    rel.setTag("Txt:" + position);
    final ImageView checkBox = (ImageView) rel
            .findViewById(R.id.checkedIcon);
    if (position == curSelected) {
        checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mPosition = curSelected;
    } else {
        checkBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }

    checkBox.setTag(position);
    dateText.setTag("text:" + position);

    final RelativeLayout rel1 = rel;

    // click Listener of day list
    rel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int checkslot=0;
            String seletedPosition = (String) v.getTag();
            String[] splitted = seletedPosition.split(":");
            int tag = Integer.parseInt(splitted[1]);
            mPosition = tag;


            clearChecked(v, parent);

            ImageView checked = (ImageView) rel1.findViewWithTag(tag);

            if (null != checked) {
                checked.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                checked.setTag("Checked");
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }


        }
    });

    return rel;
}



void clearChecked(View view, View parent) {
    // clearing current selecting
    ImageView checkedBox = (ImageView) parent.findViewWithTag(curSelected);
    if (checkedBox != null) {
        checkedBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        checkedBox.invalidate();
    }
    // getting new current selection
    String tag = view.getTag().toString();
    String[] splittedTag = tag.split(":");
    Logging.i(TAG, "[clearChecked]", "Selected: " + tag);
    curSelected = Integer.parseInt(splittedTag[1]);
    // setting new current selection
    ImageView newChecked = (ImageView) parent.findViewWithTag(curSelected);
    if (newChecked != null) {
        newChecked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        newChecked.invalidate();
    }

}


}
```

I am switching  my imageview visibility. Yo have to change the drawable in those place.

Comment: but when i click on another item,the previous item is also in blue but it change into gray color.

Comment: You have to use a flag over there by setting tag to the view which you are clicking . and use a boolean for the arrow(button/checkbox) to set is as selected. when you redraw , you make sure that you change the drawable of only the particular arrow which you have set the selected boolean as true .

Comment: see my edited answer. hope this may help coz i had simillar requirement to switch the visibility of an image based on what is clicked. You can find the logic, you have to implement some of your own code i guess.